# show method for controller on a has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models

```
thing.rb
has_one :subthing

subthing.rb
belongs_to :thing
```

And am routing with

```
resources :thing do
  resource :subthing
end

resources :subthing
```

However, my show method on my controller

```
def show
  @subthing = Subthing.find(params[:id])
end
```

when I visit

```
http://example.org/things/1/subthing
```

is giving me an error

Couldn't find Subthing without an ID

I sort of feel like this should be being taken care of by the framework... i.e it should work out that the relevant Subthing is the one that belongs to Thing.

Am I missing something or can I not use the same controller method here for Subthings on their own and Subthings when they're part of a thing.

Or do I need to explicitly tell the controller for each potential association. i.e.

```
def show
  if params[:thing_id].present?
    @subthing = @thing.find(params[:thing_id]).subthing
  else
    @subthing = Subthing.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately explicitness is required here AFAIK. Your code at the end is absolutely fine.

Comment: Ok. Was just wondering if I was missing something or if there was a clever way to absorb. Polymorphic associations will be a pain in the bum then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending to use the same `SubthingsController` for both the nested resource as well as the top level resources, then yes, you need to do as proposed:

```
def show
  if params[:thing_id].present?
    @subthing = @thing.find(params[:thing_id]).subthing
  else
    @subthing = Subthing.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

But your controller gets complicated very quick and its not worth it. You are better off re-defining your routes or use two separate controllers.